# When I run 'flutter run --release' or 'flutter build ios', the size of Runner.app is 400M, why does it so big?

Tags: flutter

sdk:1.12.13

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
  http:
  camera:
  path_provider:
  device_info:
  image_picker:
  flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

Comment: try to see your assets, maybe you paste something there

Answer (score 0):

About this question, I have the result: I guess apple store or xcode will do something such as reducing the app size after I upload my app to apple store or TestFlight.

Because, today, I ask my workmate who had installed my project from TestFlight how large the app is, then he show me the size is 19.6M,
so I reupload my app to TestFlight, at one of the steps, I found some information about "reduce the app size...", 
so I guess, apple store or xcode do something to reduce the size, but we dont't know.